# Javascript calculate increase or decrease in change from one year to the next

Tags: javascript, statistics

I have the following data for sales:

```
2018: 2
2017: 0
```

I want to calculate the change as a percentage. Here is my code:

```
var thisYear = 2, lastYear = 0;

var chg = stat = ( ( ( thisYear - lastYear ) / lastYear ) * 100 ).toFixed( 0 );
```

I get the following answer: `+Infinity`

I understand that the division is by zero to the result is zero. What is the most elegant way to handle this? I guess as a percentage it's 200% increase since I have twice as many sales as last year?

Comment: Saying that the increase as percentage it's 200% is incorrect, since it's not possible to calculate (or you could consider it infinity). Looking at my Linkedin profile views chart, in weeks wich I have 0 profile views, the next week omits the percentage regardless of the number of views, wich makes more sense to me

Comment: this question is not so much a code question: are you asking us if the first time, when the value is 0, you should show the percentage?

Answer (score 0):

Split out a bit. But is this what you are looking to achieve?

```js
var thisYear = 2, lastYear = 0;

var difference = thisYear - lastYear;
var multiplier = (lastYear == 0) ? 100 : ( 100 / lastYear );
console.log((difference*multiplier).toFixed(0));

//var chg = stat = ( ( ( thisYear - lastYear ) / lastYear ) * 100 ).toFixed( 0 );
```